# Enumerate Java Fields

Tags: java

I have a Java class with ~90 fields.  I want to be able to do things to every field (generate an XML element for instance) without writing the same 5 lines of code with slight substitutions 90 times.  In Objective C I think you can get to instance variables in ways similar to accessing Dictionary elements (ObjectForKey).  Is there anything similar in Java such that I can get an array of the fields then do something to each of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's called [Reflection API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

In particular, `MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields()` will return a full list of fields declared by this class ([see API for details](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields()))

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach: Use the [Introspector API](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) with the JDK to obtain bean-like properties of a class. This is helpful if you have getters and setters for your class and do not want to access the private fields directly. 
Obtain a BeanInfo via the Introspector and get all the [propertyDescriptors](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html) from it. To find getter of that property.

I'll have to admit that using this API is a bit cumbersome and reflection (suggested by Nikita Rybak) is more straight forward.

But there's a utility [Apache BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) that does all the hardwork internally so working with beans becomes simple.

Add:

If you are using the reflection API, I'd suggest you annotate your bean fields or your getters with a custom annotation.

```
public class MyClassWith90Fields {

   @XmlSerialize("name")
   private String screenName;  // shoudl serialize as <name>...</name>

   @XmlSerialize
   private String email;  // shoud serialize as <email>...</email>

   @XmlSerializeIgnore
   pirvate boolean flag; // shoud not serialize as annotated as ignore
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
public @annotation XmlSerialize {
   public String value;
}
```

Once done, your generation code can check (using reflection) annotated fields and serialize them to XML appropriately.